# Rails DB seeding multiple levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am new to this process and I am a bit lost. I'm trying to create a seed file for my database but I'm having trouble finding a means to create all the needed relations across the different tables.

The following is an error I am getting regarding my merchants, I need to somehow associate multiple items to a merchant and I think it will satisfy the error. The notes I was referencing show something akin to `merchant_1.items.create(...)` but I'm not sure how to integrate that with the other relations I need to create for items and so on..

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "items_id" violates not-null constraint
```

- `Merchants` have many `Items`
- `Items` have many `Reviews`

Join Table **Items - Orders**

- Many `Items` have `Orders`
- `Orders` have many `Items`

At the very end is my current schema. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# Merchants
  merchant_1 = Merchant.create(
    name: Faker::Name.name,
    address: Faker::Address.street_address,
    city: Faker::Address.city,
    state: Faker::Address.state,
    zip: Faker::Address.zip,
  )

  merchant_2 = Merchant.create(
    name: Faker::Name.first,
    address: Faker::Address.street_address,
    city: Faker::Address.city,
    state: Faker::Address.state,
    zip: Faker::Address.zip
  )

// this doesnt appear to be a solution
  merchant_1 << item_1
  merchant_1 << item_2
  merchant_2 << item_3


  # Items
  item_1 = Item.create!(
    name: Faker::Name.name,
    description: Faker::Lorem.sentence,
    price: Faker::Number.number(digits: 2),
    image: Faker::Lorem.word,
    active: false,
    merchant_id: merchant_1.id 
  )

  item_2 = Item.create!(
    name: Faker::Name.name,
    description: Faker::Lorem.sentence,
    price: Faker::Number.number(digits: 2),
    image: Faker::Lorem.word,
    active: false,
    merchant_id: merchant_1.id 
  )

  item_3 = Item.create!(
    name: Faker::Name.name,
    description: Faker::Lorem.sentence,
    price: Faker::Number.number(digits: 2),
    image: Faker::Lorem.word,
    active: false,
    merchant_id: merchant_2.id 
  )

  # Reviews
  review_1 = Review.create!(
    title: Faker::Lorem.word,
    content: Faker::Lorem.sentence,
    rating: Faker::Number.number(digits: 1),
    item_id: item_1.id
  )

  review_2 = Review.create!(
    title: Faker::Lorem.word,
    content: Faker::Lorem.sentence,
    rating: Faker::Number.number(digits: 1),
    item_id: item_1.id
  )

  review_3 = Review.create!(
    title: Faker::Lorem.word,
    content: Faker::Lorem.sentence,
    rating: Faker::Number.number(digits: 1),
    item_id: item_3.id
  )


  # Orders
  order_1 = Order.create!(
    name: Faker::Name.name,
    address: Faker::Address.street_address,
    city: Faker::Address.city,
    state: Faker::Address.state,
    zip: Faker::Address.zip_code
  )

  order_2 = Order.create!(
    name: Faker::Name.name,
    address: Faker::Address.street_address,
    city: Faker::Address.city,
    state: Faker::Address.state,
    zip: Faker::Address.zip_code
  )

  order_3 = Order.create!(
    name: Faker::Name.name,
    address: Faker::Address.street_address,
    city: Faker::Address.city,
    state: Faker::Address.state,
    zip: Faker::Address.zip_code
  )

  item_orders_1.create(
    price: 3,
    quantity: 5
  )

  item_orders_1 << [order_1, item_2]
```

**Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_12_17_013010) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "item_orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "item_id", null: false
    t.bigint "order_id", null: false
    t.index ["item_id"], name: "index_item_orders_on_item_id"
    t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_item_orders_on_order_id"
  end

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.integer "price"
    t.string "image"
    t.boolean "active"
    t.integer "inventory"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "merchant_id", null: false
    t.index ["merchant_id"], name: "index_items_on_merchant_id"
  end

  create_table "merchants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.integer "zip"
    t.bigint "items_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["items_id"], name: "index_merchants_on_items_id"
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.integer "zip"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "content"
    t.integer "rating"
    t.bigint "item_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["item_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_item_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "item_orders", "items"
  add_foreign_key "item_orders", "orders"
  add_foreign_key "items", "merchants"
  add_foreign_key "merchants", "items", column: "items_id"
  add_foreign_key "reviews", "items"
end
```

Comment: The issue is not the seeding but the schema itself. `items_id` presence in the `merchants` table seems just wrong. If you want to model "Merchant has many items" you have to add `merchant_id` FK to the `items` table. If you need many-to-many, a separate join table is necessary. Just clarify the relations between merchants, orders and items, model them properly and you will have zero problems with the seeding process...

Comment: dang, ok let me rethink how to build this out. Thank you!